# /bin/bash gives me the error inside docker container

Tags: linux, bash, docker, containers, docker-container

i have been trying to cope with sh, but there have been multiple problems being arose. I need /bin/bash inside Docker Container. But when i run this command it gives me the error `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown`.
i think i need to get bin/bash inside the container. But dont know how?

Terminal Command: `sudo docker exec -it 35f4fb7c0b0d /bin/bash`

Terminal Output: `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: does the container have bash installed?

Comment: No bash doesn't seems to be installed. Is there any way to install bash manually with sh. Or is there any way to configure docker to build images with preloaded bash.

Comment: use or extend from a diff image

Comment: You meant to say that it should have installed using Dockerfile while building the image. So in my case i didn't installed it. So do i have to extend it?

Comment: Ohh Yes, i didn't get that. You clicked me up. Thanks a lot! i have solved the problem by installing bash using Dockerfile at the time i build it. Now its been working fine.

Comment: yeah or that.. it sound like your using alpine, anything just a few mb, wont have many things installed, either switch base image or install it, you can always push your own base image derivative and use that

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped me alot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

If your image is using an alpine version then it comes pre-loaded with the "sh" which is "Bourne shell" similar to "bash", you don't need to install the bash again you can simply use the "sh" instead of "bash".

```
sudo docker exec -it 35f4fb7c0b0d sh
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your participation. I have found the solution. Which is, you need to install /bin/bash in your container through Dockerfile. But it makes the container loaded and i dont think so thats a good practice. So, therefore i opted out to go with SH for minor amendments.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The problem was bash was not present in there in container. So i need to install it by specifying it in the Dockerfile. It then be available in container.

`RUN apk update && apk add bash`

Thanks [Lawrence Cherone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone)